# unable to call custom methods on backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My model and collection looks like this.

```
var MyModel= Backbone.Model.Extend({

    foo: function(){
         alert("is not working...");
    }
});

var MyCol = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    models:MyModel,
    url: function(){ return '/json_from_server' },  //json data mapped to MyModel
    poo:function(){
      alert("this works");
    }   
});

cols = new MyCol();

cols.fetch({

    success:function () {
    cols.poo(); //this works fine
        cols.models.forEach(function(item){
            alert(item.get("id")); //It works fine
            alert(item.foo());   // this is not working... 
        });     
    }
});
```

when invoking item.foo(), the browser throws the error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'foo'
Can anybody help me to figure out what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `MyCol` object, you set `models: MyModel`. I believe models should not be plural, so it should be `model: MyModel`.

If that still doesn't work, you might need a _.bindAll in your MyModel like so:

```
var MyModel= Backbone.Model.Extend({
    initialize: function() {
         _.bindAll(this, "foo");
    },
    foo: function(){
         alert("is not working...");
    }
});
```

The reason your initialize didn't work earlier was because as stated above, you had "models" as plural when it should just be `model`.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a `bindAll` in initialize should fix it.

```
var MyModel= Backbone.Model.Extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
    },
    foo: function(){
        alert("is not working...");
    }
});
```

Comment: Still didn't work. one thing I noticed, initialize method is not being called(which I assumed it should) when collection is fetched. I found cols is populated with models but 'initialize' of the model is not called.  I wonder why?

Comment: I created model object outside: var mod = new MyModel(); mod.foo(); this works even without using _.bindAll(this). I don't know why its not working when its fetching through collections.

Comment: I think there is the some issue using fetch. Instead, I used following and it works. I will appreciate if anyone still have solution using fetch.

$.getJSON('//json_from_server', function (data) {
            if (data) {
                  var cols = new MyCol();
                 _(data).map(function (i) {
                    cols.add(new MyModel(i));
                });
            }
        });